# Connect to SQL Server through IP address

Tags: sql-server, ip-address

I'm developing tools using vb.net framework 4, and I need to connect to company server through IP address, so staff will be able to use the apps from home.

I have tried many types of connection string but I'm still  getting this error:

> Error in inserting to DB  A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.)

My connection string :

```
Data Source=xxx.xx.xxx.xxx\serverName\SQL2012,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;
Initial Catalog=xxxxx;User ID=xxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxx;
```

Comment: To confirm , I already modify sql server setting . TCP/ip enable, Named pipe Enable ,

Comment: and you have network connectivity to the machine and allowed port 1433  into the box via any firewalls (Software/hardware) that might be in between the client and the server. The reason I ask is you mention users from home  are you using a vpn?

Comment: Make sure that in your server's firewall (if there is a firewall) the port you use (1433) is open.

Comment: ooooh i did not notice that , you think the problem from firewall , can you direct me to any website which show me how to configure firewall for windows server 208, and what id VPN ..... thanks

Comment: is this server on the public internet or on a work lan?  VPN is a virtual private network, used to connect from your home to your office securely for example.  Running your sql server open to the world is generally not a good security practice.

Comment: im using live server , the point of this tools just to upload new data into my website , normally it is weekly uploading files, so i need to be on internet , once uploading done , other user able to view.i build apps caz it is much better if i use web based tools,  im not sure if there other way ,

Comment: Refer this- http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/433687/sql-server-connectity-over-the-internet

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here are couple more things you can try.

Check if sql server is configured to listen on that IP address. If your server has multiple IP addresses that doesn’t necessarily mean that it can automatically accept connections from all IPs.

To set this go to SQL Server Configuration Manager -> SQL Server Network Configuration -> Protocols for {instancename} -> TCP/IP -> IP addresses tab

Here is also some info that will guide you when setting up firewall. 
What you want to do with the firewall is to enable TCP and UDP traffic on port 1433 for both incoming and outgoing traffic.

http://www.howtogeek.com/112564/how-to-create-advanced-firewall-rules-in-the-windows-firewall/

Now, if you have physical firewall or some other software firewall other than windows default you’ll have to contact your network admin

Answer (score 5):

Right idea, you just overelaborated.

If the SQL Server is the *default* instance on that computer, you can just specify it as:

```
Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

If it's a named instance, specify it as

```
Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\INSTANCENAME
```

For SQL Express instances, it is generally:

```
Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\SQLEXPRESS
```

If there're multiple instances running on the same server, you may need to leave the SQL Browser Service running (it is generally disabled by default).

There is a *fantastic* web resource out there at http://www.connectionstrings.com.   They provide the syntax and options for connecting to just about any kind of server database that's out there.

Also, when working through SQL connectivity problems, it's always helpful to turn off your firewall on the server machine until you have everything worked out, and then re-enable it and work through the firewall issues afterwards.   It just makes life more difficult when you're trying to address multiple potential issues all at once.