# Connecting to a SQL Server in another domain

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ado.net, active-directory, database-connection

I have a SQL Server in another domain that I need to query against.  I haven't been able to find anything online similar to what I'm trying to do so I'm coming here for help.  Normally, I've been using Window's Remote Desktop Connection to log onto the other domain and then I would open management studio from the remote machine and execute my queries.

I would like to have code do what remote desktop connection does without the graphical interface.  I just want my code to remote into the other domain, execute a query, and disconnect.  Here's what I have:

```
Private Sub btnConnect_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnConnect.Click
    Dim connectionString As String = "Server = 111.111.111.111; Initial Catalog = remote database; Network Library=DBMSSOCN; integrated security = true; User ID = domain2\mylogin; Password = myPass;"
    Dim connectionString2 As String = "Server = local SQL Server; Initial Catalog = local database; integrated security=true"

    Try
        Using sourceConnection As SqlConnection = _
        New SqlConnection(connectionString)

            Dim commandSourceData As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand( _
                                "SQL Query", sourceConnection)

            sourceConnection.Open()
            Dim reader As SqlDataReader = commandSourceData.ExecuteReader()

            Using destinationConnection As SqlConnection = _
                New SqlConnection(connectionString2)
                destinationConnection.Open()
                Using bulkCopy As SqlBulkCopy = _
                    New SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection)
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Column1", "Column1")
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "local database"
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader)
                End Using
                destinationConnection.Close()
            End Using
            reader.Close()
            sourceConnection.Close()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

I get the following error:

[image]

Yes, my SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

Comment: You cannot specify a user if using integrated security. You need to use SQL security authentication on your remote server.

Comment: Removed that from my code.  Got the same error.

Comment: How are you using integrated security when the two machines are on separate domains and would likely not know anything about each other?

Answer (score 1):

In your connection string:

```
Server = 111.111.111.111; Initial Catalog = remote database; Network Library=DBMSSOCN; integrated security = true; User ID = domain2\mylogin; Password = myPass;
```

You are specifying to use integrated security *and* providing credentials which will not work. Integrated security always uses the currently logged in user (or the user the process is running as).

So to run with specified credentials, you will need to enable SQL security on your remote server (`111.111.111.111`) and then create a SQL user account with the appropriate permissions to `remote database`.

Then modify your connection string accordingly:

```
Server = 111.111.111.111; Initial Catalog = remote database; Network Library=DBMSSOCN; User ID = SqlAccountName; Password = SqlAccountPW;
```

Answer (score 0):

Although all the other answers are correct with regards to specifying integrated security and a user name, I do not think that is your only problem. From the error you are getting, the server cannot be located. You can check the following...
- Can you ping 111.111.111.111
- Is there a firewall on the remote server?, and has it been configured to allow SQL Connections
- Is the SQL Server browser service started?
- Is the TCP/IP protocol enabled in SQL Server Network Configuration

Here's a answer to a question with the same error as yourself with some more things you can check.

[Connect to SQL Server through IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17737568/connect-to-sql-server-through-ip-address)

Hope that helps