# Connecting SQL Server to vs on different networks

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2012, connection-string, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012

I couldn't find an answer so I'm posting it here.

I want to know if it's possible to connect from Visual Studio to SQL Server based only on IP address when the two servers are not in the same domain or workgroup?

I've allowed remote connections and opened port 1433 on both servers with no luck. One server is 2008r2 and the second is 2012r2. The SQL Server version is 2012.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's certainly possible. Since they aren't in the same domain, you won't be able to use windows authentication. But you can use a SQL login.

I believe this is a duplicate question of:
[Connect to SQL Server through IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17737568/connect-to-sql-server-through-ip-address)

That shows you other steps to check for answering by IP address only.

Comment: I've already been through all the steps in the pther thread. The problem was only resolved after the servers where in the same domain, when I changed the IP address to the server name.

Comment: I've tried to connect from two different servers, each had its own problems. I can conclude by saying it is possible. Thank you!