# mssql_connect() Unable to connect to server to Remote host from php hosting

Tags: php, sql-server

I have working mssql connecting codes and them working in my another company php host but dont work when i moved new host. All codes same i dont know why connect from new host ? In new host using cpanel and php ( Hostgator ) and im looking php.ini in cpanel mssql settings looking good. my codes below under.

```
$usernameb ="myuser";
$passwordb = "mypass";
$databaseb = "mydb";
$host ="myhostip"

$connection = mssql_connect($host, $usernameb, $passwordb);
if (!$connection) {  die('Not connected : ' . mssql_get_last_message());} 


$db_selected = mssql_select_db($databaseb, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mssql_get_last_message());
} else{


}
```

And gives that error on my new hosting

> Warning:  mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server: ip here in

Any idea ?

Comment: Sounds like a networking issue, not a php issue. Either there is no sql server listening on that remote system or access is blocked, either by a firewall or by simple network topology.

Comment: @arkascha sql server side not have firewall or blocked etc.. at another host working same codes i think new host maybe have block etc. how can i see if it that ?

Comment: Can you connect from a tool besides PHP using the same details?

Comment: @Hiphop03199 yeah connect with navicat , connect at old host with same codes only my new host gives that error

Comment: Where is the DB hosted, on the server with the already working code or a third server?

Comment: @chris85 db hosted in windows sql server 2012

Comment: Not OS, where, physical location? Is it a third server or one of the two?

Comment: @chris85 in europe connect with adsl

Comment: Well, simply try a direct connect from your php executing system to the sql server using a simple telnet call: `telnet <sql server address> <sql server port>`. What happens?

Comment: @arkascha with telnet and with navicat connecting success

Comment: Em... you really checked that in less than 30 seconds including reading my question? I somehow doubt that...

Comment: @arkascha i checked before i did everything

Comment: So how did the telnet utility react? What did it say?

Comment: @arkascha with navicat says me Connection Successful this enough for me also same codes working at old host.

Comment: So you did _not_ check with `telnet`, but just claimed you had? OK, I am out. bye.

Comment: Do you specify the instance name? I only see IP (myhostip) and DB Name (mydb), and no port? no instance name. Also this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17737568/connect-to-sql-server-through-ip-address#17743540