# Remote Select Query for Microsoft Sql Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014

How to Run Select Query to Remote MSSQL Server... using IP address

**e.g.** 
suppose myip address is :: 45.34.223.44
and my database name is AccountsWarehouse... Table Name is :: SalesData

I want to Make Select SQL query by supplying IP address

Comment: Um ... `SELECT * FROM [AccountsWarehouse].[SalesData] WHERE ip = '45.34.223.44'` ?

Comment: linked server? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine

Comment: i hope this will help... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17737568/connect-to-sql-server-through-ip-address

Answer (score 0):

Write your Queries in script files in a directory on your PC.

Place a batch file with the following in that directory with the following Contents:

for %%d in (*.sql) do echo.>>Log.txt & echo ---Begin %%d--->>Log.txt & echo.>>Log.txt & sqlcmd -S 192.168.30.150 -d MyDatabaseName -U dbUserId -P DBPassword -i"%%d">>Log.txt & echo.>>Log.txt & echo ---End %%d--->>Log.txt