# Spring boot in app engine connection with cloud sql

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

Trying to connect spring boot application deployed at app engine standard environment with cloud MySql throws following error.

GCLOUD: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot connect to MySQL server on localhost:3,306.
GCLOUD: Make sure that there is a MySQL server running on the machine/port you are trying to connect to and that the machine this software is running on is able to connect to this host/port (i.e. not firewalled). Also make sure that the server has not been started with the --skip-networking flag.

```
config.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
config.setJdbcUrl(String.format("jdbc:mysql:///%s", DB_NAME));
config.setUsername(USER_NAME);
config.setPassword(USER_PW);
config.addDataSourceProperty("socketFactory", "com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.socket.factory.connector.j.8");
String CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME = "PROJECTID:REGION:DB_INSTANCE";
config.addDataSourceProperty("cloudSqlInstance", CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME);
```

'IAM' roles and other setting made in app engine as suggested [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine).
Am I missing something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't connect to Cloud SQL Database using JDBC through Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58495312/cant-connect-to-cloud-sql-database-using-jdbc-through-android-studio)

Comment: I am using HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig(); So its throwing an error (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError) on using 'socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory'.

Comment: Are you sure you have created a database (not only an instance)?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same thing, and (several headaches later) came across a solution that works for me. It came down to the dependencies stated in pom.xml (for maven).

I was using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.22.0</version>
</dependency>
```

which I think I got from some other tutorial.

Instead, replacing it with the following fixed the issue:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.16</version>
</dependency>
```

This I found through a tutorial video (in itself quite helpful): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mAhah-vq0Iw