# Connect App Engine to Google cloud SQL fails

Tags: kotlin, google-app-engine, jvm, google-cloud-sql

I'm following this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-standard#java)

I'm filling the config like this:

```
val datasourceConfig = HikariConfig().apply {
    jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql:///$DB_NAME"
    username = DB_PASS
    password = DB_USER
    mapOf(
        "cloudSqlInstance" to CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME,
        "socketFactory" to "com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory",
        "ipTypes" to "PUBLIC,PRIVATE",
    ).forEach {
        addDataSourceProperty(
            it.key,
            it.value
        )
    }
}
```

output of the `gcloud sql instances describe project-name`:

```
backendType: SECOND_GEN
connectionName: project-name:europe-west1:project-name-db
databaseVersion: MYSQL_5_7
failoverReplica:
  available: true
gceZone: europe-west1-d
instanceType: CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE
ipAddresses:
- ipAddress: *.*.*.*
  type: PRIMARY
kind: sql#instance
name: project-name-db
project: project-name
region: europe-west1
```

from which I'm filling my env variables:

```
DB_NAME=project-name-db
CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME=project-name:europe-west1:project-name-db
```

On the deployed app line `val dataSource = HikariDataSource(datasourceConfig)` crashes with the following exception:

```
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: Cannot connect to MySQL server on localhost:3,306.

Make sure that there is a MySQL server running on the machine/port you are trying to connect to and that the machine this software is running on is able to connect to this host/port (i.e. not firewalled). Also make sure that the server has not been started with the --skip-networking flag.
```

update: I've tried adding `google` between second and third slashes(`"jdbc:mysql://google/$DB_NAME"`), according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58495312/cant-connect-to-cloud-sql-database-using-jdbc-through-android-studio), now I get:

```
Cannot connect to MySQL server on google:3,306.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't connect to Cloud SQL Database using JDBC through Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58495312/cant-connect-to-cloud-sql-database-using-jdbc-through-android-studio)

Comment: I've tried adding google between second and third slashes, now it says `java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot connect to MySQL server on google:3,306.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was missing the following dependency:

```
implementation("com.google.cloud.sql:mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-8:1.2.2")
```

more info [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory/blob/main/docs/jdbc-mysql.md)

Also `DB_NAME` is not name of `gcloud sql instances` output, but a database name that should be created in Console -> Project -> Sql -> Databases